# Why Isn't my powershell reading what I send over the network stream

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, tcp, tcpclient

So I made a server in C# which accepts a socket connection as a TCP client.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(Address, PORT);
    listener.Start();
    var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

    Console.WriteLine("Client has connected!");

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Powershell Command: ");
        var cmd = Console.ReadLine();
        client.Client.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd));
    }
}
```

And I'm I'm trying to connect to it using Powershell, and it connects just fine.

```
$tcpConnection = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($args[0], $args[1])
$tcpStream = $tcpConnection.GetStream()
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($tcpStream)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($tcpStream)

$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024
$encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding 

while ($tcpConnection.Connected)
{
    while ($true)
    {
        $rawresponse = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, 1024)
        $rawresponse.Length
        $response = $encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $rawresponse)  
        Write-Host $response
    }
}

$reader.Close()
$writer.Close()
$tcpConnection.Close()
```

The problem is that when I send a message from the server, powershell prints out
`0`
 
so just a 1 and a blank space. Even if I send the string `"Test"`

Why is that? And how do I properly make it print out the string `"Test"` when I send that

Comment: have you checked `$RawResponse`? does that have more than one char? does it contain ANY of the chars sent to it?

Comment: `$RawResponse` contains `0x04`

Comment: Assume that you receive one complete packet, is not realistic.

Comment: @JohnA - that is `4` in dec ... and that seems to match the _length_ of the sent item - `Test`.  that sure sounds like "the buffer has 4 chars in it". what happens when you send "this is NOT a test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of subtle bugs in your code:

**Buffer Length**

First, from the documentation for the [StreamReader.Read(Char[], Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=net-6.0#System_IO_StreamReader_Read_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_) method:

> Returns
>
> Int32
>
> The number of characters that have been read, or 0 if at the end of the stream and no data was read. The number will be less than or equal to the count parameter, depending on whether the data is available within the stream.

Your `$rawresponse` already contains the number of characters written to the buffer, so you don't need to use `$rawresponse.Length`. However, just to keep you on your toes PowerShell automatically adds a default `Length` and `Count` property to all variables if they don't already have one - for example:

```
PS> $x = 4
PS> $x
4
PS> $x.Length
1
PS> $x.Count
1
```

so you're outputting PowerShell's "length" of the variable with the line `$rawresponse.Length`, not the number of characters written to the buffer. (I can't find a good reference for this behaviour, but I believe it's basically to help with processing objects in a pipeline).

Remove the `.Length` and you'll display the correct value.

**Buffer Type**

The other problem is this line:

```
$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024
```

If we go back to the documentation for StreamReader.Read(Char[], Int32, Int32), it says the parameters are:

> public override int Read (char[] buffer, int index, int count);

Note the buffer is a `char[]`, not a `byte[]`. If you tried this in C# you'd get a compiler error, but PowerShell tries to be helpful and will convert your `byte[]` variable into a temporary `char[]` variable when it invokes the `Read` method. It *won't*, however, convert the result back and put it into the original `byte[]` variable afterwards, so any changes made to the temporary buffer by `Read` method are lost.

If you change your code to:

```
$buffer = new-object System.Char[] 1024
```

You'll get the desired output because the original buffer is passed to the `Read` method:

```
response = 'test'
```

**Buffer Length (again)**

As an aside, you should also read your buffer in a loop *for each command* until `Read` returns 0 because there's no guarantee it exhaust the stream in a single read. See the code in the link above for an example...